# Transform a column of data into many columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, transform, reduce, transpose

I have data that looks like this:

```
a <- data.frame("Type" = replicate(5, "A"),
                "Day" = replicate(5, "Monday"),
                "Zone" = c(1:5),
                "Class" = c(0, 0, 1, 2, 3))
```

And I am trying to transform the `Zone` column such that each entry is a new column and such that under each `Zone` column is the corresponding value from the `Class` column.
So far, this is what I have:

```
library(reshape2)
library(plyr)
b <- dcast(a, Type+Day+Class~Zone)

b <- plyr::rename(b, c("1" = "Zone_1",
                       "2" = "Zone_2",
                       "3" = "Zone_3",
                       "4" = "Zone_4",
                       "5" = "Zone_5"))
```

That results in this:

```
  Type    Day Class Zone_1 Zone_2 Zone_3 Zone_4 Zone_5
1    A Monday     0      0      0     NA     NA     NA
2    A Monday     1     NA     NA      1     NA     NA
3    A Monday     2     NA     NA     NA      2     NA
4    A Monday     3     NA     NA     NA     NA      3
```

However, I am trying to get this:

```
  Type    Day  Zone_1 Zone_2 Zone_3 Zone_4 Zone_5
1    A Monday       0      0      1      2      3
```

Any suggestions on how to get the table reduced like this?
Also, if someone has a better way of renaming the columns (if needed) then I would like to see that as well since my way seems very repetitive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a <- data.frame("Type" = replicate(5, "A"),
                "Day" = replicate(5, "Monday"),
                "Zone" = c(1:5),
                "Class" = c(0, 0, 1, 2, 3))

library(tidyverse)

a %>%
  mutate(Zone = paste0("Zone_", Zone)) %>%  # update Zone column
  spread(Zone, Class)                       # reshape data

#   Type    Day Zone_1 Zone_2 Zone_3 Zone_4 Zone_5
# 1    A Monday      0      0      1      2      3
```

As suggested by @zack in the comments below, we don't need to update our variable in advance if we use the `sep` argument within `spread` like this:

```
a %>% spread(Zone, Class, sep = "_")
```

Comment: Just a note, you can add a `sep` argument to `spread` which takes care of the `mutate` step you have: `a %>% spread(Zone, Class, sep = "_")`

Comment: @zack please post your comment as an answer

Comment: It's only a minor modification to @AntoniosK's answer, he can update his post with  the code if he likes. The `spread` verb here is the important piece of the solution.

Comment: Really good to learn something new! Never used that argument before. I'll update my solution

Answer (score 2):

Using data table you could try the following:

```
    library(data.table)

    a <- data.frame("Type" = replicate(5, "A"),
                "Day" = replicate(5, "Monday"),
                "Zone" = c(1:5),
                "Class" = c(0, 0, 1, 2, 3))
    setDT(a)
    dcast(a, Type + Day ~ paste0("Zone_", Zone), value.var = "Class")

     Type    Day Zone_1 Zone_2 Zone_3 Zone_4 Zone_5
        A Monday      0      0      1      2      3
```